# Specify Multiple File Types, GLOB, Python 3.6

Tags: python, glob

I have a large amount of html and css files (maybe for types to come).

I have written a find and replace script using glob which works great on 1 file type..

im having trouble iterating over multiple file types.

************UPDATE***********

This code works perfectly!  thanks guys

```
files_extensions = ('.html', '.css')
find_str = 'http'
replace_str = 'https'

def find_and_replace(find, replace):
    for files in files_extensions:
        globby = (glob.glob('**/*' + files, recursive=True))
        print(globby)

        for file in globby:
            f = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
            file_data = f.read()
            f.close()

            new_data = file_data.replace(find, replace)

            f = open(file, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
            f.write(new_data)
            f.close()


find_and_replace(find_str, replace_str)
```

Comment: try `print`ing `file_ext` - it doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: it does lol, it prints out .html ... i somehow want it to send .css and .html and also more types like .php, .js etc  to the function... apologies for not clarifying.. i just put the and there to highlight what im looking to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'll give you an example of how to grab more than one type, I think you will be able to use this example in your code, but if you have some trouble, ask for it!

```
files_extension = ('*.html', '*.css')
all_files_with_extension = list()
for files in files_extension:
   all_files_with_extension.extend(glob.glob(files))

print all_files_with_extension
```

Comment: i have a very similar script at the top but i must have screwed up as mine creates 2 lists, one with just html and one with html and css.. your displays only one.. ive swapped my one for yours so thanks.. im still have trouble iterating though lol